# Automatic show a dialog in ObjectListView, wxpython

Tags: dialog, wxpython, objectlistview

I meet a problem in ObjectListView. When I choose some objects or use checkbox to choose them, the function on those objects will be called by pressing a button and utilizing GetCheckedObjects(). 
[image]

Is it possible for a dialog showed automatically when I choose or check an object like this?
[image]

If ObjectListView doesn't support that function, is there any other ways to realize it?

Comment: @Mike Driscoll As an expert in wxpython, can you help me to assess these two problems?

Comment: @ tags only work if the person you're trying to talk to has already posted a message in the thread you're commenting on. I.e. that would only work if Mike had already left a comment.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576067/wxpython-wx-evt-list-item-selected-not-working-when-same-item-is-clicked-twice-i), the event that is triggered when a user clicks on a `ObjectListView` is the same as for a `wx.ListCtrl`, namely `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED`.

So all you need to do is create your dialog (tutorials [here](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/dialogs/) and [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial/#Custom_dialogs)) then bind a function to `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED` that launches your dialog.